# rehash in insert function in C

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to rehash a hashtable which have been implemented using separate chaining approach.
I have linked list for each bucket of the hashtable and need to resize and rehash the table when load factor (#nodes/#buckets) is greater than 0.75
I try to copy just the tail of each bucket of the original table into a temporary table and free the previously allocated memory for the table(map->hashtable) then increase the size of table by doubling the size.Then I malloc a new table (array of linked list structs) to store entries after resize and rehash process. 
The aim of the function is to add an entry to the table . I am not sure how I can rehash the nodes of the original table in new table. This is what I have done for checking the size. Any hint would be appreciated

```
size_t index = (map->hash_func(k)) % (map->size_map);
    float load_factor = map->node_count / map->size_map ;
    if (load_factor >= 0.75) {
        struct linked_list *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list) * map->size_map);
        for (int i = 0; i < map->size_map) {
            temp_array[i].tail = map->hashtable[i].tail;
        }
        free(map->hashtable);
        map->size_map *= map->size_map;
        map->hashtable = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list) * map->size_map);
```

Comment: What's your question? Don't you get the desired behaviour? Some observations from your description: (1) You don't need to copy the existing buckets to a new temporary memory. Just use the old memory before free'ing it. (2) "I try to copy just the tail of each bucket" -- Surely you mean the head of each bucket, no? (3) `map->size_map *= map->size_map` -- You square the number of buckets with each resize. That will grow huge rather quickly. (A more usual approach would be to double the size each time.)

Comment: There is a missing `; i++` part in your `for (int i = 0; i < map->size_map) {` loop

Answer (score 0):

Your hashtable implementation uses an array of linked lists to store the key-value pairs:

```
hash->table[0] -> ("dec", 31) -> NULL
hash->table[1] -> NULL
hash->table[2] -> ("aug", 31)  -> ("jun", 30) -> NULL
...
hash->table[n] -> ("feb", 28) -> NULL
```

The index of the linked list, i.e. which "slot" an item is stored in, is determined by the hash value of the key module the current hash table size. All entries in a list have the same hash value module the size. This invariant is always true.

When you resize the hash table, you must re-organize your linked lists. You don't need to create new list nodes, just re-link the nodes, so that the invariant is true for the new list.

- Create a new table of the new size. Initialize all pointers in that new table to `NULL`.
- Process each list in the old table:

  - Calculate the hash value. That value modulo the new size is the index `i` of the slot in the new table.
  - Remove the node from the old list and insert it into slot `i` of the new table.
- Delete the old table, which now holds only obsolete list heads.
- Set the new table and size.

If you double the size – don't square it as in your example –, you should more or less halve the length of your lists. For example if you have 32 slots and increase the size to 64, about half of the items that were in slot 5 are in slot 5 in the new list, too. The rest of the items should be in slot 37.

A resizing function might look like this:

```
void map_resize(Map *map, size_t size)
{
    if (size > map->size) {
        Node **table = malloc(size * sizeof(*table));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            table[i] = NULL;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < map->size; i++) {
            Node *node = map->table[i];

            while (node) {
                Node *next = node->next;
                size_t h = hash(node->key) % size;
                Node **p = &table[h];

                while (*p && strcmp(node->key, (*p)->key) < 0) {
                    p = &(*p)->next;
                }

                node->next = *p;
                *p = node;

                node = next;
            }
        }

        free(map->table);

        map->table = table;
        map->size = size;
    }
}
```

(For the sake of clarity, that code does not do any error checking on the allocations, which your code definitely should do! [Here's](https://ideone.com/k3YY0T) the code above in a full example.)